# Canvas to Multiple Images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've created a canvas of size `1240x3500`.

I need to convert it to a pair of images., i.e., from  `(0,0)` to `(1240,1750)` and from `(0,1751)` to `(1240,3500)`.

Is is possible to achieve this using `toDataURL()` or is there any other function to establish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such a method available out of the box. Good news is that it's quite simple to make:

- create a new (off-screen) canvas the size of the region
- clip-draw the part of the original image into the new canvas
- call toDataURL() on the new canvas

One way:

```
function regionToUri(canvas, x, y, w, h) {

    var ncanvas = document.createElement('canvas'), // create new canvas
        ctx = ncanvas.getContext('2d');

    ncanvas.width = w;                              // set it to target size
    ncanvas.height = h;

    ctx.drawImage(canvas, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);  // use region draw

    return ncanvas.toDataURL();                     // return data-uri
}
```

Modify the return statement if you need another format than PNG (or better, supply a parameter for this as well).

```
var dataURI = regionToUri(originalCanvas, x, y, w, h);
```

Note: For this to work your original image must fulfill CORS requirements.